# How to make original text cell disappear when double clicking to make it an editing field?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```
<td     TEMPLATE
                  id="original-table-data"
                      class="flex-table-cell"
                      v-for="header in tableHeaders"
                      :key="header"
                      v-if="checkedHeaders.includes(header) && !tableInEditMode"
                      :style="{ width: `${header[1]}%` }"
                      @dblclick="enableEditing(item, header)"
                      :id="`original-table-data-${itemIndex}-${index}`"
                    >
                      <input
                        v-if="item.editing && item.editingField === header"
                        v-model="item[header.toLowerCase()]"
                        @blur="disableEditing(item)"
                        @keydown.enter.prevent="disableEditing(item)"
                        ref="editableInput"
                      />


METHODS

                 enableEditing(item, header, elementId) {
                  this.$set(item, "editing", true);
                   this.$set(item, "editingField", header);
                   this.$nextTick(() => {
                   this.$refs.editableInput[0].focus();
                 });
                   this.hideOriginalData(elementId);
                  },
                 disableEditing(item) {
                this.$set(item, "editing", false);
                 this.$set(item, "editingField", null);
                  },
```

I am trying to create a textbox that when you double click it, becomes an editable text box - EXACTLY the same way excel does. I have the textbox showing up and the double click function working in enableEditing - but the element I clicked on is staying displayed and moving aside the text box

So for instance if there is a "names" column and I double click the name "Alice Smith" - a text box will pop up in place of that cell, but then the cell displaying "alice smith" also appears to the right, when I click enter, then the new cell appears in its place and the other one disappears, but i want the original cell to disappear when double clicked.

[image]

Comment: Hey, what do you mean by, `when I click enter, then the new cell appears in its place and the other one disappears`?

Comment: Also, please provide some more code. This code is so incomplete to say anything.

Comment: yeah i have to get better at asking questions i have 0 idea how to make my point using words. 

what i mean is i have a table, the table has cells (think excel)

the cells have data. you can double click the cell, and an input field pops up so you can edit that cell. But when the input field pops up, the original element i clicked on also stays displayed on the DOM. so it would be a text box, and the original thing i clicked, rather than the original thing i clicked disappearing and there only be a text box, how you'd expect it to work

Comment: heres a picture, the code isn't incomplete this is all the code you need to solve this. the @dblclick handler enableEditing is the only thing that is making this action happen